# StanfordCoreNLP Error: No such trained tagger config file found

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am using StanfordCoreNLP library (stanford-corenlp.jar) and I get an error while executing below lines of code.

```
protected StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;

public LemmatizerHelper() {
    Properties props;
    props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref");

    this.pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props); // Error occurs from this line
}
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
Adding annotator tokenize
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator pos
Loading POS Model [edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/wsj3t0-18-left3words/left3words-distsim-wsj-0-18.tagger] ... Loading default properties from trained tagger edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/wsj3t0-18-left3words/left3words-distsim-wsj-0-18.tagger
Error: No such trained tagger config file found.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: edu\stanford\nlp\models\pos-tagger\wsj3t0-18-left3words\left3words-distsim-wsj-0-18.tagger (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerConfig.getTaggerDataInputStream(TaggerConfig.java:737)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerConfig.<init>(TaggerConfig.java:185)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerConfig.<init>(TaggerConfig.java:130)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:240)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:69)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.<init>(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:43)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:496)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:489)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:62)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:325)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:374)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:364)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:356)
at irproject.LemmatizerHelper.<init>(LemmatizerHelper.java:25)
at irproject.PreProcessingHelper.Lemmatization(PreProcessingHelper.java:59)
at irproject.IRProject.main(IRProject.java:30)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:     java.io.FileNotFoundException: edu\stanford\nlp\models\pos-tagger\wsj3t0-18-left3words\left3words-distsim-wsj-0-18.tagger (The system cannot find the path specified)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:498)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:489)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:62)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:325)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:374)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:364)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:356)
at irproject.LemmatizerHelper.<init>(LemmatizerHelper.java:25)
at irproject.PreProcessingHelper.Lemmatization(PreProcessingHelper.java:59)
at irproject.IRProject.main(IRProject.java:30)


Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: edu\stanford\nlp\models\pos-tagger\wsj3t0-18-left3words\left3words-distsim-wsj-0-18.tagger (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerConfig.getTaggerDataInputStream(TaggerConfig.java:737)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:667)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:280)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:240)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.loadModel(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:69)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.POSTaggerAnnotator.<init>(POSTaggerAnnotator.java:43)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:496)
... 9 more
```

This is where I downloaded the jar file
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadstanfordcorenlpjar.htm

I am using Netbeans IDE 8.1

Answer (score 1):

You should get Stanford CoreNLP 3.7.0 from this site:

http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

Make sure to have all of the jars from the downloaded folder in your CLASSPATH.  Not having stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models.jar in your CLASSPATH will lead to the type of error you are seeing.